# Mean value of DataFrame columns based on Columns name extension

Tags: python, string, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, mean

I have a DataFrame **A** in Jupiter that looks like the following

```
Index Var1.A.1  Var1.B.1  Var1.CA.1  Var2.A.1  Var2.B.1  Var2.CA.1
0      1         21         3          3         4        4 
1      3         5          4          9         5        1
....
100    9         75        2           4         8        2
```

I'd like to assess the mean value based on the extension of the name, i.e.

- Mean value of .A.1
- Mean Value of .B.1
- Mean value of .CA.1

For example, to assess the mean value of the variable with extension .A.1, I've tried the following, which doesn't return what I look for

```
List=['.A.1', '.B.1', '.CA.1']
A[List[List.str.contains('.A.1')]].mean()
```

However, in this way I get the mean values of the different variables, getting also CA.1, which is not what it look for.

Any advice?

thanks

Comment: What is expected output of sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want `mean` per rows by all values after first `.` use `groupby` with lambda function and `mean`:

```
df = df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('.', 1)[-1], axis=1).mean()
print (df)
     A.1   B.1  CA.1
0    2.0  12.5   3.5
1    6.0   5.0   2.5
100  6.5  41.5   2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a thrid option:

```
columns = A.columns
A[[s for s in columns if ".A.1" in s]].stack().reset_index().mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

`dfA.filter(like='.A.1')` - gives you the column containing the '.A.1' substring